# Boundedness of a linear mapping implies its continuity betwee two normed vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, continuity, normed-spaces

I would like to show the following implication :  $(E,\lVert\rVert_{E})$ and $(V,\lVert\rVert_{V})$ are two normed vector spaces.

Consider $f : E\to V$ a linear mapping, if $\lVert f(x)\rVert_{V}$ is bounded  for $x$ in the unit ball of $E$ then $f$ is continuous on $E$

My attempt : We have that: $\exists M>0,\forall x\in N(0_{E}, 1) :\lVert f(x)\rVert_{V}\leq M$

We want to show : $\forall x\in E, \forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall y\in E : \lVert y-x\rVert_{E}\leq\delta\implies\lVert f(y) - f(x)\rVert_{V} =\lVert f(y - x)\rVert_{V} \leq\epsilon$

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Remark that $v = \frac{y-x}{\lVert y-x\rVert_{E}}\in N(0_{E}, 1)$  so there exists $M>0$ such that $\lVert f(v)\rVert_{V}\leq M$ and put $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$. Then we have

$\lVert y-x\rVert_{E}\leq\delta\implies\lVert f(y-x)\rVert_{V}\leq M\delta = \epsilon $

Indeed, we have by hypothesis $\lVert f(v)\rVert_{V}=\lVert f\left(\frac{y-x}{\lVert y - x\rVert_{E}}\right)\rVert_{V} = \frac{1}{\lVert y - x\rVert_{E}}\rVert f(y-x)\rVert_{V}\leq M\implies \lVert f(y - x)\rVert_{V}\leq M\delta = \epsilon$

Is this seems correct ?

Thank you

Comment: It is correct except "We have that: $\forall x\in N(0_{E}, 1), \exists M>0 :\lVert f(x)\rVert_{V}\leq M$" which is trivially true and is not the formal translation of  "$f$ is bounded on the unit ball". Also, your title would be more appropriate if you replace "betwee two infinite dimensional vector spaces" by "between two normed vector spaces".

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment ! What is the formal translation of "$f$ is bounded on the unit ball" please ?

Comment: Same but with $\exists M$ [...] *before* $\forall x$ [...], because $M$ must not depend on $x$ (otherwise it would obviously exist).

Comment: @AnneBauval  Oh yes sorry for this mistake. Thank you !!